# How to use jsdoc options in jsdoc-grunt task

Tags: jsdoc3

I want to add the `-p` flag in order to generate documentation for private methods using `grunt-jsdoc`. How can I do that?

According to the documentation at [grunt-jsdoc](https://github.com/krampstudio/grunt-jsdoc) they state that we can use any of the options specified in the [useJsDocCli](http://usejsdoc.org/about-commandline.html), however do not know how they should be specified in the grunt task. Here is my current grunt task:

```
jsdoc : {
            dist : {
                src: ['app/scripts/directives/*.js','README.md'],
                options: {
                    destination: 'doc'
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I specify that I want the task to run with the `-p` flag (or any other flags)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example in the documentation under the template section https://github.com/krampstudio/grunt-jsdoc#templates

Just use the flag name without the dash, for example:

```js
dist : {
    src: ['app/scripts/directives/*.js','README.md'],
        options: {
          destination: 'doc',
          private: true
        }
    }
}
```